# Validate phone XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

i want need help about validate phone number when the first number have some static number for every phone. like phone number for home,and company or and from handphone , i want trying detecting and validate the number was valid or not. how to take number after 62 and 021. thanks for help

Sample number :

```
6281234567890 and 02141234567
```

Comment: Please clarify exactly what is a valid number.

Comment: there was 2 types input. with 62 and 021 at first input. example : 0214123451431 and 62812341231. so the plan. i need to take the number after 62 and 021

Comment: That would be extraction, not validation.

Comment: You also may want to consider getting rid of nonnumeric characters first like this translate($inNumStr,translate($inNumStr,'0123456789',''),'').  And then testing for length using string-length. And, if nonnumeric characters are a problem, then you could test for those as follows:  translate($inNumStr,'0123456789','') != ''.  But give us examples of bad numbers and good numbers...

Answer (score 0):

> i need to take the number after 62 and 021

You could do something like:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="starts-with(phone, '021')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(phone, '021')" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="starts-with(phone, '62')">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(phone, '62')" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>???</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Don't see what this has to do with validation.